# sql: change primary key to another list of unique elements

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to change the ids of a table to some other unique value.
This is a simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  reverse_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY reverse_id (reverse_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO  test (id, reverse_id) VALUES ('1',  '2'), ('2',  '1');

UPDATE test SET id = reverse_id;

# Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I am looking for a command that checks only at the end of the UPDATE for the uniqueness of the id elements.

[I know that I can create a second row and change the status of this row to primary, then i can update the ids and reset the primary status, but i want to have one command, without adding or changing other rows, tables]

Comment: You can drop the primary key, but then MySQL will simply create a hidden integer primary key, thereby violating your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with MySQL as far as I know.

It neither evaluates constraint on statement level (it does that on row level while processing) nor does it allow you to define them to be deferred (so the constraint would be evaluated at commit time).

The only option I can see if you want to "renumber" your primary key: drop the primary key, renumber the ids then re-create the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create the table having `reverse_id` as its primary key? - that is unique in your definition so it is a valid candidate for primary key.

Primary keys are unique by definition - this constraint is stopping you from achieving what you want